# a weird ssh file appearing from nowhere with name pbcopyfy in .ssh directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

Well not a question as such, but more of a brainstorming thing or better say an issue. Well today I came to my server and realised that i can't git pull due to the keys being denied which was okay because for sure there were no  keys in .ssh directory. All deleted and a new file (pbcopyfy there). Not sure what this means though. The content of the file are shown below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright (C) 2009-2017 Three Nine Consulting
#  Always good practice to update packages. However ask user if they would like to do so
#  For explanation on how this works and why check out https://garywoodfine.com/use-pbcopy-on-ubuntu/
read -p "Do you want to update your package repositories before proceeding ? " -n 1 -r
echo  #adding new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade -y
   sudo apt autoremove -y
fi



#  Check to see if Xclip is installed if not install it
if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' xclip 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ];
then
   echo 'xclip not installed .... installing now!'
   sudo apt install xclip -y;
fi
#  Add the aliases to the .bashrc
echo 'updating bash profile'
echo "#pbcopy & pbpaste aliases" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'"  >> ~/.bashrc
source  ~/.bashrc


echo 'Complete! happy PbCopy'
```

Is this something I should be worried about or should I just get new keys and go up and running with new keys?

Comment: If somebody other than you deleted the contents of your `.ssh` directory, I would say that is *definitely* a reason for concern. I would speak to the system administrator.

Comment: apparently, I am the system admin and there has been no one else in for a couple of months now and I didn't delete anything in the directory